# .net-WCF How do we create a client programatically?

Tags: wcf

How do I create a client programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Visual Studio command prompt and move to client application folder using change directory command and type

```
svcutil.exe http://your_service_url/your_service_name.svc?wsdl
```

This will generate a configuration file (output.config) and a client class. 
Client class name will be **your_service_nameClient**
Next you need to copy the **<system.serviceModel>** section from output.config to your App/Web config. Now your client application is ready to consume the service.
You can create client class object and invoke service methods.

Hope this will help you

Comment: You may want to add reference to System.Runtime.Serialization, System.ServiceModel

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to start the `svcutil.exe` process -- it could be done from a program, but it will generate source code, not binary code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to WCF check out this site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784.aspx

If you are only interested in learning how to create a client, this is the video for you:

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/Endpoint-Screencasts-Creating-Your-First-WCF-Client/